# Rails DateTime object isn't what I expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a Java developer who is very new to Ruby so if this question is a little too basic, please go easy on me.  :)  I'm here to learn if someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm writing an application that deals with times and will need to take time zones into account.  I was curious what Ruby offers for dealing with timezones and I found that Rails provides a DateTime class that should do what I need.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-in_time_zone

However, when I create a DateTime, it doesn't seem to have the methods I expect.  Can someone explain what is going on here?  Here is what I'm seeing in irb:

```
>> dt = DateTime.now
NameError: uninitialized constant DateTime
    from (irb):1
>> require 'rails'
=> true
>> dt = DateTime.now
=> #<DateTime: 212158799144191849/86400000000,-1/4,2299161>
>> dt.respond_to? "in_time_zone"
=> false
```

Since DateTime isn't defined until I require rails, I assumed I was using the Rails DateTime but it doesn't seem to have the methods I'm expecting based on the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`DateTime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/DateTime.html) is a core class, and part of [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html). It is available if you `require 'date'` in your code; You don't have to use Rails to access it.

```
require 'date'

asdf = DateTime.parse(`date`)
asdf # => #<DateTime: 2010-12-10T21:41:59-07:00 (212158802519/86400,-7/24,2299161)>
asdf.class # => DateTime
asdf.to_s # => "2010-12-10T21:41:59-07:00"
```

The class you're after is part of ActiveSupport, which is part of Rails, but you don't have to load Rails to access it:

```
require 'active_support/all'
asdf.in_time_zone # => Fri, 10 Dec 2010 21:43:42 -0700
```

or

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
asdf.in_time_zone # => Fri, 10 Dec 2010 21:59:48 -0700
```

Ruby's [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html) class has good support for timezones also, so you might want to [get familiar with it](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) too.

Comment: That's good information for a newbie like myself.  Although,  I still don't have the in_time_zone method mentioned in the Rails documentation I provided the link for.  I'm under the impression that Rails has an enhanced DateTime class (or maybe just enhances the existing one) with better support for dealing with time zones.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Rails enhances the standard classes. I use Time when I need to fiddle with timezones and offsets.

Comment: So, at what point does Rails make those enhancements?  Even if I used Time, I would have the same problem - Ruby's Time class is fairly minimal when it comes to dealing with time zones and I would need Rails' enhancements.

Comment: "at what point does Rails make those enhancements?"? When the `require` is executed.

Comment: Then is there anything about my example that's preventing Rails from adding the methods?  I'm requiring rails prior to creating the DateTime but it doesn't have any of the Rails DateTime methods.

Comment: Don't `require 'rails'`. You need what is in ActiveSupport, so require that like I show above. [Read the ActiveSupport documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#stand-alone-active-support) to understand what is happening.

Comment: Ah, much better!  I didn't see the edits to your original post until now.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need whole Rails stack for timezone support. You can install and use just active_support. But you can as well check out [`tzinfo`](http://tzinfo.rubyforge.org/doc/) gem.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder what's happening here.  I tried requiring active_support and it seems to have worked (require "active_support" returned true) but DateTime.now still doesn't have the extra methods like in_time_zone.